# firewalld and NAT

Tags: debian, networking, nat, firewalld

So i have been given a task to get to know firewalld and linux networking in general. This is my test setup:

[image]

Router and Client are running Debian 12, Laptop Ubuntu 22.04.

This setup should accomplish following goals:

1. Router should obviously act as a router between the subnets 192.168.8.0/24 and 192.168.7.0/24
2. Laptop and client should be able to ping each other
3. Traffic from client should be natted over 192.168.8.120 if source ip is 192.168.7.120
4. Traffic from client should be natted over 192.168.8.121 if source ip is 192.168.7.121
5. Firewalling on router with firewalld standard features, no direct rules

My problem is to achieve 5. No matter what i try, traffic is always natted via 192.168.8.120.

This is the firewalld-config:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=ext0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --set-target=default
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --add-forward 
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --change-interface=enp1s0:0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --add-source=192.168.7.120
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext0 --add-source=192.168.8.100/32

firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=ext1
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --set-target=default
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --add-forward
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --change-interface=enp1s0:1
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --add-source=192.168.7.121
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=ext1 --add-source=192.168.8.0/24
```

I used various configs which only differs slightly in terms of interface names, because i tried different device types:

- Virtual interfaces, problem i see here is that both devices like
  enp1s0:0 and enp1so:1 share the same MAC address. Tried to assign new
  local MAC-addresses and also tried wrapping each of the interfaces
  into a bridge.
- VLANs, same problem, also tried assigning MACs and
  wrapping into bridges.
- Dummy interfaces, seem to be invisible to the outside world, wrapping into bridges didnt help.

Basic thought was: Two zones, one for traffic over 192.168.8.120 and one for 192.168.8.121. Add to each zone the "outgoing" interface with the corresponding IP, turn on masquerade and forward and finally add the "incoming" interfaces or IP-Adresses as sources. Turns out that adding interfaces isnt enough, it only works when adding IP-Sources.

Another problem i see is that i cant add the same source to different zones in firewalld (notice the sources 192.168.8.100/32 and 192.168.8.0/24). AFAIK IP sources takes precedence over interfaces and zones are processed in alphabetical order, so at least traffic from 192.168.8.100 (for example echo replies) will be stuck in zone ext0.

Since firewalld documentation suggests that rich rules should only be a last resort i havent really dived into that yet (will do that now, any pointer apreciated).

So what am i doing wrong? Can this be accomplished with firewalld basic features?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Hint: `enp1s0:1` is not an interface. It's an address with a label. So for the various commands it won't match (or for some commands, it's considered same as enp1s0 instead). Don't use `ifconfig` which is the only command really affected by this that sees this address as an interface (use `ip link` and `ip addr` instead). This is only a hint, I'm not using often firewalld.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what is not working.  Also, firewalld may be necessary but not sufficient.  You may also need routing rules to get between the various networks.

Comment: Agree with former comments, and offer my hint: do not forget enable IPv4 forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.